# svg out of screen, is rendered?

Tags: performance, svg

Scenario: I have SVG image that I can zoom-in and zoom-out. Depending on the zoom, I will display more/less details on the visible part.

The question is: should I take care of *not* displaying details on the parts that are not currently visible (out of the screen), or the rendering engine is smart enough to skip (clip) those parts *before* they are rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, browsers are usually clever enough to not render things outside the viewport area.

Note however that the browser still needs to traverse the entire document tree, so even things outside the viewport area can have an impact. It's usually enough to mark the non-interesting subtrees with `display="none"` to let the browser skip over them when traversing. On small documents that's usually not something that you need to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

I guess clipping will always be applied to the current viewport. But you are probably changing the DOM by updating with the detail visibility changes and restricting that to the visible parts only can make a difference.

The easiest way to find this out is to measure, though. Make two prototypes, one with manual clipping, one without and look for differences in rendering speed in various renderers.