# Does a svg compute outside of viewbox?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have several objects moving outside of the viewbox of a svg in react. For the sake of optimisation, I would like to conditionally render it. So the objects outside would not be rendered. But I'm asking myself if it's really needed. Does an SVG compute what is outside of a viewbox?

Comment: How do you know what parts of an SVG are outside of the viewbox?

Comment: I just do a 2.5d effect, so I have a prop for the pixels parcoured in the x axis. I know where is everything that way, and just need some calculation regarding the width of the viewbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the browser computes everything outside the viewport for rendering. Calculates but does not display in the viewbox. Therefore, the question is relevant only in terms of rendering performance. If a part of a very large svg file with a lot of small details is outside the viewBox then rendering will be difficult. Although this will only show the visible part of the SVG.

*comments of the author of the question:*

> I just do a 2.5d effect, so I have a prop for the pixels parcoured in
> the x axis. I know where is everything that way, and just need some
> calculation regarding the width of the viewbox

### Calculating the width of the viewport

Below is an example with two SVG shapes. One figure is inside the svg viewBox, the second is outside

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300" style="border:1px solid" >  
  <g>
<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="200" rx="5%" fill="purple" />
           <!-- Circle cx = "800" outside viewBox = "0 0 600 300" -->
<circle cx="800" cy="150" r="140" fill="greenyellow" />
</g>
</svg>
```

***The circle is outside the svg of the canvas so it is not rendered in the browser***

This is how it looks in the vector editor

[image]

In order for both figures to be inside the svg canvas, you need to calculate the parameters of the viewBox.
To do this, put both shapes in the group tag `<g>` and calculate the parameters of the viewBox

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="300" viewBox="0 0 600 300" style="border:1px solid" >  
         
  <g id="group">
<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="200" rx="5%" fill="purple" />
           <!-- Circle cx = "800" outside viewBox = "0 0 600 300" -->
<circle cx="800" cy="150" r="140" fill="greenyellow" />
</g>
</svg>     

<script>
 console.log(group.getBBox())
</script>
```

***Setting the computed viewBox attributes***

It was: viewBox="0 0 600 300"

Now: viewBox = "20 10 920 280"

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="600" height="300" viewBox="20 10 920 280" style="border:1px solid" >  
         
  <g id="group">
<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="200" rx="5%" fill="purple" />
           <!-- Circle cx = "800" inside viewBox = "0 0 920 280" -->
<circle cx="800" cy="150" r="140" fill="greenyellow" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I don't think they want to find the viewBox that will show everything, they just want to know if it's worth the trouble to do themselves `allElements.filter(isOutOfViewBox).forEach(el=>el.style.display = "none")` or if the renderer does this automagically. Everything after "Although this will only show the visible part of the SVG."  seems quite irrelevant. And this question has already been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723490/svg-out-of-screen-is-rendered

Comment: @Kaiido   Let's wait for the author of the question. And we will not speak for him what he wants.  I answered this final comment here.  "I just do a 2.5d effect, so I have a prop for the pixels parcoured in the x axis. I know where is everything that way, and just need some calculation regarding the width of the viewbox"

Comment: which was a response to the previous comment "How do you know what parts of an SVG are outside of the viewbox?"

Comment: @Kaiido This is a comment from another person, not the author.

Comment: Yes, they won't respond to themselves...

Comment: Yep you're right Kaiido, I'm not trying to change the viewbox aha and the linked post were responding my simple question. I tryed a conditionnal render for the parts outside of viewbox to check today, and it's indeed more fluid. Thanks Alexandr for the detailed answer even though it's a little outside of the questions, i might not have been clear enough.